# Compute $[F(x):F (\frac{x^2}{x-1})]$ in a simpler way.

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

I have to compute $[F(x):F (\frac{x^2}{x-1})]$. I proved it by setting a isomorphism between them. I think setting homomorphism between two fields cannot be an answer if degree is not $1$. Is there any other simple way to compute it?

Comment: Sure, $\frac{x^2}{x-1}\in F(x)$, but is it really true that $x \in F\left(\frac{x^2}{x-1}\right)$?

Comment: you need to be more careful with parentheses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $y = \frac{x^2}{x-1}$. [Then we have](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+y+%3D+x%5E2%2F%28x-1%29+for+x) $x = \frac12(y\pm\sqrt{y(y-4)})$. This means that $x$ is (one of) the root(s) of the following polynomial in $F(y)[t]$:
$$
(2t - y)^2 -y(y-4) = 4t^2 - 4ty + 4y = 4(t^2 - ty + y)
$$
so the degree is (at most) $2$.

Comment: Thanks :) the remaining part is to determine whether plynomial is irreducible or not. right?

Comment: I got it thanks!!